# Django text formatting in template

Tags: django, python-3.x, django-templates

I am trying to format text rendered from database in django template.

```
#models.py

class Question(models.Model):
    quiz = models.ForeignKey(Quiz, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='questions')
    text = models.TextField('Question', max_length=1500)
    def __str__(self):
        return self.text
```

the text what i am entering in the text field is like

```
a=50
b=30
c=a*b
```

Now When I am calling this value in the template like.

```
#template.html

<p>{{ question.text }}</p>
```

the text is printing like below in the template

```
a=50 b=30 c=a*b
```

I want the text to be formatted with line breaks while calling the values in template

```
a=50
b=30
c=a*b
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this in tour template, it will do the trick for you

```
#template.html

<p>{{ question.text|linebreaks }}</p>
```

Answer (score 0):

try this it will work!

```
{% for q in question %}
    <p>{{ q.text }}</p>
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: thanks for your effort, but your answer is not relevant to my question